# memcpy() overflow? Every eighth byte has its same bit pulled down when reading from FLASH

Tags: c, arm, embedded

**The problem**

When executing a memcpy() to copy 8kb from a FLASH memory region (aligned on sector boundary) to a buffer allocated on the heap, a seemingly un-related printf() statement is mangled.

I have tried to copy fewer bytes, doing it parts, using a buffer allocated on the stack instead of on the heap, etc. However, in all these cases, the mangling is still happening, so it seems that purely the execution of the memcpy() itself is already causing this problem.

**The code**
Unfortunately, the code is aimed at an embedded platform, so reproducing the problem is likely troublesome. Nevertheless, this is where the corruption happens (at the memcpy()):

```
uint8_t *pInitReadBuffer = malloc(nvsRegionAttrs.regionSize);
if (!pInitReadBuffer)
{
  printf("Could not allocate memory (%s:%d)\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);

  return;
}

// TODO Fix this
memcpy((void *) pInitReadBuffer, nvsRegionAttrs.regionBase, nvsRegionAttrs.regionSize);
```

**The disassembly**

```
84         memcpy((void *) pInitReadBuffer, nvsRegionAttrs.regionBase, nvsRegionAttrs.regionSize);
            $C$L3:
0000a51c:   4920                ldr        r1, [pc, #0x80]
0000a51e:   4A21                ldr        r2, [pc, #0x84]
0000a520:   9800                ldr        r0, [sp]
0000a522:   6809                ldr        r1, [r1]
0000a524:   6812                ldr        r2, [r2]
0000a526:   F001FEDB            bl         #0xc2e0
101         free(pInitReadBuffer);
```

**The data**

Original string: `[GPRS]: Waiting for GPRS UART task to start up`
Mangled  string: `KGPRS]: Gaiting for GPRS UART tack to start up`

*What does this show us?* That every eighth character (byte) is being mangled. In fact, the mangled characters show us that even their same bit is being pulled down. The ASCII value of **K** (75) is 16 less than that of **[** (91). The same goes for the **W** that became a **G**, and the **s** that became a **c**.

**Extra information based on the comments of Jonathan Leffler, Chris Stratton, and D Krueger**

- Not a multithreaded environment, single processor running RTOS
- **Always the first printf() after the memcpy() is mangled**
- Optimization levels do not affect the behavior
- Reading any FLASH region produces the same behavior
- Reading less does not affect the behavior
- **Printing a formatted string from the stack changes the mangled output** to 
  `KGPRS]: Gaiting for GPRS UART task to start up`, so that is one less malformed character, but still 2 remaining
- **Reading a non-FLASH region does help**, indicating that D Krueger might be right
- **If any printf() is added before the printf() that is currently being mangled (first statement of the one and only task that is being started by the RTOS), the problem does not show**

Unfortunately, I do not understand what is causing this weird behavior, and how to solve it, even with all this information.

I would very much appreciate some insight!

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: Why on earth are your printf strings in RAM? Does the problem persist if you move them to another part of RAM (like .data)? You can place a write hardware  breakpoint on said strings and see what code that is overwriting them.

Comment: Note that the `a` in `start` didn't get changed.  Bit 4 of `a` is already 0. This looks a bit as if it might be a hardware fault — it certainly isn't normal behaviour for a `memcpy()` to change bits. That the change happens outside the copied regions (source and target) is also puzzling — that may indicate some software problems, but it is weird to be resetting (zeroing) one bit in every 8-byte unit (as if doing `data[i] &= ~0x00000010ULL` on the data, though the 1 bit in the constant could be in a different position in the number: `0x10000000ULL`, `0x00100000ULL` or `0x00001000ULL`, etc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately, the code runs on an embedded platform. 
I will add some code of the specific parts to the main topic.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I completely agree. Sadly, the manufacturer is very reluctant to give meaningful feedback.

Comment: @Lundin I did not manually change the location of the printf strings. But I can look into your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembler generated for the `memcpy()` operation?  Does that give you any insight?  Does changing the optimization level when compiling that file change the behaviour?  Does reordering the list of object files on the link line change the behaviour?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If we assume a 64-bit word then it's the same bit in each word, i.e. 0x1000000000000000 big endian or 0x0000000000000010 little endian.  If `memcpy` is copying using full words, this could indicate an "off" bit in a register.

Comment: @dbush — yes: I wondered if I was going to be called out for economizing on the number of zeroes :D  The "etc" covers the cases you suggest, but it isn't explicit.  Something to do with 600 character limits in comments.  (Any excuse in an emergency.)

Comment: I don't know much about ARM assembly, but perhaps a small piece of embedded assembly that reads/writes specific registers could reveal the problem.

Comment: You malloc a chunk or `.regionSize` bytes, and try to store `.sectorSize` in it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have added the disassembly to the main topic.

Comment: Is this a multithreaded environment?   What is the time relation between the memcpy and the printf?  If you do the memcpy once and keep doing the printf does it stay wrong? **What exactly is the hardware and software platform and how is the printf output being captured**?  Just saying it is an "embedded system" is not meaningful enough - it is no dodge to the reproducibility requirement for debugging questions here, rather it is part of the information required to meet that.

Comment: You should perhaps also try this in related contexts - other boards with the same SoC, other software contexts, and see if you can get the behavior to change based on any of clock speed, optimization level, or inserting / removing extra things in the code which would change the memory map of the build and run.  Check the platform / OS documentation for known errata like cache issues especially if the system is multicore or if memcpy might be DMA-based.  What happens if you substitute your own simple memcpy?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the hardware platform remains unidentified despite a specific request that this critical information be provided

Answer (score 4):

The issue has nothing to do with the function shown, but with code called previously. Somewhere the FLASH array was placed in command mode and never returned to read mode. The "corrupted" bits seen are actually set to zero by the device to communicate the FLASH command status.

Two likely causes of this behavior:

- A FLASH command is executed but the command to return to read mode isn't.
- The read-mode command is issued, but without waiting for completion of the prior FLASH command.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I will look into the previously called manufacturer code and see if we can learn something from that. I hope to find something and will let you know!

Comment: This seems to assume a lot of things having no supporting evidence in the question - that the flash even *has* a "command mode", that the string constant would come from the same flash, and that the rest of the executing code would not.